# Unable to locate bootstrap classes

Tags: css, joomla

I need to edit class .col-lg-8 on my website

[Here is what I am trying to locate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiQtq.png)

And

[Here is what my FTP looks like when trying to locate the less folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arpyo.png)

Due to this I'm assuming I can just find the class in the bootstrap.css file? I have found and edited the required class in this stylesheet but no change on my website. The cache takes a while so veryifying here in the meantime.

Fyi I'm using Joomla.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Alex, your question might be more welcome at Joomla Stack Exchange. Rather than editing the bootstrap or template files directly, it is usually best to add custom CSS as an override so your code is not overwritten by the next Joomla or template update. For details, see the answers to the question at: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/3877/120

Comment: Since Alex is new, could downvoters please leave a comment with some suggestions on how the question could be improved or why it's not welcome here? Thank-you.

Comment: @AlexE I haven't downvoted you, but the downvotes are probably because volunteers dislike having to chase hyperlinks to understand the question.  Do try to post text as much as possible and avoid screenshots unless absolutely necessary.  As Neil has mentioned, if you have Joomla-centric questions, you will find the community to be much friendlier and better equipped with Joomla knowledge.  Furthermore, some people may not like your question because it states that you are waiting to see if your best attempt to self-solve was actually successful -- not much to answer in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You must disable the less in your template to do this  go to : Extensions > Templates > styles  and should click on active template in theme panel , There is probably an option to disable the less